# Importing multiple tables from files in Sphinx in .rst format

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to import multiple tables from multiple source `.csv` files in a single `.rst`. Something like below `.rst` sample:

```
=======
Section
=======

subsection01
------------
.. csv-table:: my_table1
   :file: my_file1.csv

subsection02
------------
.. csv-table:: my_table2
   :file: my_file2.csv
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/var/jenkins_home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/environment/__init__.py", line 612, in get_doctree
    doctree = pickle.load(f)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 4
The full traceback has been saved in /tmp/sphinx-err-IQAuoY.log, if you want to report the issue to the developers.
Please also report this if it was a user error, so that a better error message can be provided next time.
A bug report can be filed in the tracker at <https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues>. Thanks!
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'html' failed
make: *** [html] Error 2
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have to mention that if I put each `import` block above in a separate `.rst`, they will just works fine. But this is not what I need. The above message seems like a sphinx bug/issue to me.

Any thoughts/solutions on this?

Answer (score 1):

A more recent version of Python is perhaps needed to read the pickle output :)
Pickles protocol version 4 looks like it was added in Python 3.4, updating might work!

```
Exception occurred:
  File "/var/jenkins_home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sphinx/environment/__init__.py", line 612, in get_doctree
    doctree = pickle.load(f)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 4
```